# How to draw a table with annotation? (screenshot inside)

Tags: tables

I need to draw a table like this into my paper. I know to draw a table but I'm not sure how to annotate it (rows and columns) with indexes. Do you have some example how to do it in LaTex?

[image]

Comment: Please give us the code for the table so somebody can concentrate on the indices rather than having to reproduce the picture.

Comment: Are the labels on the top supposed to align with the columns?

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution with a `tikzmatrix`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells,
    nodes={draw, minimum width=8mm, minimum height=5mm, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center},
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    row 3/.style = {nodes={minimum height=8mm}},
    row 5/.style = {nodes={minimum height=8mm}},
    column 3/.style = {nodes={minimum width=10mm}},
    column 4/.style = {nodes={fill=gray}},
    column 6/.style = {nodes={fill=gray}},
    column 7/.style = {nodes={minimum width=10mm}},]
    {& & & R & & ? & & &  \\
     & & & R & & R & & &  \\
     & & & & & & & &  \\
     & & & R & & R & & &  \\ 
     & & & & & & & &  \\
     & & & ? & & R& & &  \\
     & & & R & & R& & &  \\};
    \foreach \i [count=\xi] in {1,2,\dots,$i$,$j$,$k$,\dots,$m-1$,$m$}
        \node[above, font=\scriptsize] at (A-1-\xi.north) {\i\strut};
    \foreach \i [count=\xi] in {1,2,\vdots,$l$,\vdots,$n-1$,$n$}
        \node[left, font=\scriptsize] at (A-\xi-1.west) {\i\strut};
    \foreach \i in {2,4,7}
     \draw[dashed] ([shift={(.5mm,-.5mm)}]A-\i-4.north west) rectangle ([shift={(-.5mm,.5mm)}]A-\i-6.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```