# How to annotate matrices with circles and arrows

Tags: matrices, arrows

I need to produce the following matrices with tex. How can I do it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: look on this site for questions about `tikzmatrix`.

Comment: for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236502/4686 deals with tables, this is very similar.

Comment: Please provide the code for the matrix you are having trouble with and explain the particular problem you want help with. Last time you asked one do-it-for-me. Now you want two do-it-for-mes. Since they are all matrices, I'm assuming the first didn't help you to understand this much, so it will be better if you show us where you are getting stuck so we can focus our energies there.

Comment: Or you could set the matrix and annotate using `tikzmark`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are a lot of similar posts here but, just for fun, I suggest a solution with TikZ matrices.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzset{
    mymatr/.style={    
        matrix of math nodes, 
        minimum size=16pt,
        row sep=2pt,
        column sep=2pt,
        left delimiter={[},
        right delimiter={]}, 
        inner xsep=0pt
        },
    mynode/.style={    
        draw, 
        rounded corners=9,
        inner xsep=1pt
        },
    myarrow/.style={    
        draw, 
        -Triangle
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\noindent Matrix:
\[
\underset{m \times l}{\text{M}}=
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(m.center)]
\matrix[mymatr] (m) {
    4 & 1 & 5 & 11 \\ 
    3 & 2 & 7 & 9 \\ 
    2 & 3 & 9 & 7 \\ 
    1 & 4 & 11 & 5 \\
    };
\node[mynode, fit=(m-1-1)(m-4-1)] (firstcol) {};    
\node[mynode, fit=(m-1-4)(m-4-4)] (lastcol) {};    
\node[above =1pt of firstcol] {$m_1$};
\node[above =1pt of lastcol] {$m_l$};
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=8pt,raise=9pt}]
(m-1-4.north east) -- (m-4-4.south east) node [midway,xshift=20pt, anchor=183] {$m$ features};
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
Column vector:
\[
\text{A}=
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\matrix[mymatr] (v) {
    |[draw, circle]|1 \\ 
    2 \\ 
    3 \\ 
    |[draw, circle]|4 \\
    };
\node[right = of v-1-1, text width=7cm] (firstcomm) {contribution of the first data sample in sparse coding etc.};
\node[right = of v-4-1, text depth=2pt] (secondcomm) {contribution of the $n$th data};
\draw[myarrow] (v-1-1) -- (firstcomm);
\draw[myarrow] (v-4-1) -- (secondcomm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]